# Getting Warnings With Method That Checks Device Orientation

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, orientation

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this code? I'm trying to determine what orientation (portrait or landscape, the device is in). Thanks.

```
- (void)checkOrientation
{
    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];

    switch (orientation) 
    {
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:
            self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            break;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
            self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            break;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
            self.navigationController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background2.png"]]; 
            break;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
            self.navigationController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background2.png"]]; 
            break;
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

### Warning

> Implicit conversion from enumoration type 'UIDeviceOrientation' to differnt enumeration type 'UIInterfaceOrientation

Comment: what warnings are you getting?

Comment: `Implicit conversion from enumoration type 'UIDeviceOrientation' to differnt enumeration type 'UIInterfaceOrientation`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now that you've posted the error, the problem is clear. This line:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
```

returns an instance of `UIDeviceOrientation`, not an instance of `UIInterfaceOrientation`. To remove the warning and correct the code, you can change the offending line to this:

```
UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
```

Answer (score 0):

If this code is under a viewController you should use self.interfaceOrientation to make the work.